# AJAX Object Passes Null to Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Good Day,

I am at my wits end and I know that it's probably something simple I am missing. After searching and searching I can't seem to find a solution that works for me. My problem is that I am trying to pass information from input fields via AJAX to a controller using JSON.

This is the code for my C# Model

```
public partial class EgInput
{
        public string DisplayId { get; set; }
        public string EgUid { get; set; }
        public double Quantity { get; set; }
        public string Quality { get; set; }
        public string Required { get; set; }
        public string MaxAmount{ get; set; }
}
```

This is the Code for my C# Controller Action

```
public String SaveTest(EgInput obj)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Uid Value: "+ obj.DisplayId);

    return (obj.DisplayId);
}
```

Below is the Input Fields

```
    <input asp-for="DisplayId" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="DisplayId" class="text-danger"></span>
    
    <input asp-for="EgUid" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="EgUid" class="text-danger"></span>
    
    <table>
     <tr id="eg_row">
            <td>
                <input asp-for="Quantity" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Quantity" class="text-danger"></span>
            </td>
           
            <td>
                <input asp-for="Quality" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Quality" class="text-danger"></span>
            </td>
    
            <td>
                <input asp-for="Required" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Required" class="text-danger"></span>
            </td>
    
            <td>
                <input asp-for="MaxAmount" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="MaxAmount" class="text-danger"></span>
            </td>
    
        </tr>
    </table>
<button type="button" id="save_test">Save</button>
```

This is the JavaScript I'm Executing.

```
 $('#save_test').on("click", function () {
        
        $("tr").each(function () {
            if ($(this).is("#eg_row")) {
                var did = $("#DisplayId").val();
                var eid = $("#EgUid").val();
                var quantity = $(this).find("#Quantity").val();
                var quality = $(this).find("#Quality").val();
                var req = $(this).find("#Required").val();
                var max = $(this).find("#MaxAmount").val();
                
                var obj = JSON.stringify({
                    "DisplayId": did,
                    "EgUid": eid,
                    "Quantity": quantity,
                    "Quality": quality,
                    "Required": req,
                    "MaxAmount": max
                });

                console.log("clicked");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: obj,
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    url: '/Index/SaveTest',
                    success: function (msg) {
                        alert(msg);
                    }
                }); 
            }
        });
    });
```

I have Console logged the JSON array to see that their are indeed values pulled from the fields. I have tested that the correct action in the controller is called and changed its return to a message to know that it was successfully processed. Using the is() function in C# it says that the object is indeed to the type. However, the values are always null when using Debug Console to verify the information in the object. Thanks in advance for any assistance that is provided.

Comment: can you add `error: function( msg){alert(msg);}` in the methos and see

Comment: I did add the error function, but Javascript sees it as a success and doesn't throw an error as it gets back the string even though the value is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said, it was a rather simple solution to my problem. For some reason the JSON stringify wasn't being passed. I tried using the [FromBody] attribute or the [FromUri] but the object still remained null. So instead I tried just simply passing the Javascript object directly, and did not use json and the data transferred.

Revised JavaScript Code Below

```
$('#save_test').on("click", function () {
        
        $("tr").each(function () {
            if ($(this).is("#eg_row")) {
                var did = $("#DisplayId").val();
                var eid = $("#EgUid").val();
                var quantity = $(this).find("#Quantity").val();
                var quality = $(this).find("#Quality").val();
                var req = $(this).find("#Required").val();
                var max = $(this).find("#MaxAmount").val();
                
                var obj = {
                    "DisplayId": did,
                    "EgUid": eid,
                    "Quantity": quantity,
                    "Quality": quality,
                    "Required": req,
                    "MaxAmount": max
                };

                console.log("clicked");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "html",
                    data: obj,
                    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    url: '/Index/SaveTest',
                    success: function (msg) {
                        alert(msg);
                    }
                }); 
            }
        });
    });
```